# How to change the date/time format of Go's log package

Tags: go, logging

When using the [log package](http://golang.org/pkg/log/), Go outputs something like

```
2009/11/10 23:00:00 Hello, world
```

How can I change the date and time format to something like `dd.mm.yyy hh:mm:ss`? Example ([playground link](http://play.golang.org/p/848Wa50X0d)):

```
package main

import "log"

func main() {
    log.Println("Hello, playground")
}
```

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Like yed posterior said, you can define a custom io.Writer by implementing a write function.  You'll also probably want to do a log.SetFlags(0) to take full control.  Here's an example that changes the date format as well as adds some log level info.

```
type logWriter struct {
}

func (writer logWriter) Write(bytes []byte) (int, error) {
    return fmt.Print(time.Now().UTC().Format("2006-01-02T15:04:05.999Z") + " [DEBUG] " + string(bytes))
}

func main() {

    log.SetFlags(0)
    log.SetOutput(new(logWriter))
    log.Println("This is something being logged!")
}
```

outputs:

2016-03-21T19:54:28.563Z [DEBUG] This is something being logged!

Answer (score 6):

According to the source (http://golang.org/src/pkg/log/log.go) there is no built-in way to do that:

```
26      // Bits or'ed together to control what's printed. There is no control over the
27      // order they appear (the order listed here) or the format they present (as
28      // described in the comments).  A colon appears after these items:
29      //  2009/01/23 01:23:23.123123 /a/b/c/d.go:23: message
```

You'll need to use a 3rd party package for that, or intercept the log output as yed described.

Answer (score 5):

Use a custom writer that filters the log lines to modify them to the format you need. It should be easy because the format of the header is regular and fixed-width. Then call log.SetOutput(myFilterWriter(os.Stderr)).

Answer (score 0):

It's much easier to use the flags from Logger system internal.

```
    log.SetFlags(log.Lmicroseconds)
```

Use this flag to add timestamp with microseconds to the log.
Other available options are :

```
const (
Ldate         = 1 << iota     // the date in the local time zone: 2009/01/23
Ltime                         // the time in the local time zone: 01:23:23
Lmicroseconds                 // microsecond resolution: 01:23:23.123123.  assumes Ltime.
Llongfile                     // full file name and line number: /a/b/c/d.go:23
Lshortfile                    // final file name element and line number: d.go:23. overrides Llongfile
LUTC                          // if Ldate or Ltime is set, use UTC rather than the local time zone
Lmsgprefix                    // move the "prefix" from the beginning of the line to before the message
LstdFlags     = Ldate | Ltime // initial values for the standard logger
```

)

Golang logger documentation is available [here](https://golang.org/pkg/log/#pkg-examples)

Comment: Indeed it's easier, but this does not answer the question. `log.Lmicroseconds` has nothing to do with a custom date format.