# Is there any way to format logs (like describe below) by using golang std library?

Tags: go, logging

1. ​Feb 1, 2018 at 3:04:05pm (UTC) | This is log message
2. 2018-02-01T15:04:05Z | This is log message

I found the next formats in go src:
https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/log/log.go#L37
But it seems I couldn't manage to do it by using only those ones..

Comment: Please show your current attempt, and explain what problem you're having.

Comment: No you cannot do this. (To simple for an answer).

Comment: The standard logging package (`log`) provides minimalistic formatting and customization options, see [`log.SetFlags()`](https://golang.org/pkg/log/#SetFlags) and the [flag constants](https://golang.org/pkg/log/#pkg-constants) for details. If you need more or different than that, you may look for a 3rd party logging library (there are plenty for Go).

Comment: Gotcha. Then I can't do by using std lib. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Well basically I was wrong
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26120698/how-to-change-the-date-time-format-of-gos-log-package

Answer (score 0):

Two options here:

use log.SetOutput to set a custom writer.

Or use the fmt package instead to just print to stdout or elsewhere - the stdlib log package doesn't do much and it's pretty easy to create your own log package which outputs with custom time format(s) to stdout (or a log file). For example here is such a package in a few lines:

```
package log

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

var TimeFormat = "2006-02-01T15:04:05Z"

func Printf(format string, args ...interface{}) {
    format = fmt.Sprintf("%s %s", time.Now().Format(TimeFormat), format)
    fmt.Printf(format, args...)
}
```

I'd recommend doing this yourself if you have specific needs, and just output to stdout with fmt.Printf. You don't really need a third party log package.

https://play.golang.org/p/iPeuGjQqEf4

Comment: «the stdlib log package doesn't do much» not quite true: it makes two important guarantees: 1) A single calls to any outputting method on a logger instance results in a single call to `Write` on the underlying writer; 2) These calls to the underlying writer are serializer. Hence I'd go with the first option for simplicity.

Comment: Yes that was probably a little unfair. It is worth reading the source to see what it does.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`log.SetOutput(...)`](https://golang.org/pkg/log/#SetOutput) with an argument writer that prints entries using your desired format (such as the builtin RFC3999 or one of your choice), for example:

```
const timeFormat = time.RFC3339

type logWriter struct{}

func (lw *logWriter) Write(bs []byte) (int, error) {
  return fmt.Print(time.Now().UTC().Format(timeFormat), " | ", string(bs))
}

func main() {
  log.SetFlags(0)               // Omit default prefixes.
  log.SetOutput(new(logWriter)) // Use our custom writer.

  log.Printf("Hello, %s!", "World")
  // 2018-09-18T14:50:40Z | Hello, World!
}
```

You can change the timestamp by using a different format, e.g.:

```
const timeFormat = "Jan 2, 2006 at 3:04:05pm (UTC)"

// ...
  log.Printf("Hello, %s!", "World")
  // Sep 18, 2018 at 2:52:26pm (UTC) | Hello, World!
```

Answer (score 0):

https://play.golang.org/p/hPCn3MflkgQ
Here is an answer. You should deal with Writer interface and create new Log by using it